# Windows Server 2012 R2 The interface is unknown After Renaming

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I renamed the computer name of my only DC in my test domain. However, it seems the database is not compleatly updated. I encountered 0xc00002e2 blue screen after the first reboot. Then I tried to fix it by using the ntdsutil -> Compact to commands to rebuilt the ntds.dit file.

The server was finally able to bootup normally. But, I can't use any AD services now. Here is what the dcdiag saying:

```
Directory Server Diagnosis

Performing initial setup:
   Trying to find home server...
   Home Server = dc1
   * Identified AD Forest.
   Done gathering initial info.

Doing initial required tests

   Testing server: SEA\SDC
      Starting test: Connectivity
         ......................... SDC passed test Connectivity

Doing primary tests

   Testing server: SEA\SDC
      Starting test: Advertising
         Fatal Error:DsGetDcName (SDC) call failed, error 1717
         The Locator could not find the server.
         ......................... SDC failed test Advertising
      Starting test: FrsEvent
         ......................... SDC passed test FrsEvent
      Starting test: DFSREvent
         The event log DFS Replication on server sdc.sea.nr could not be queried, error 0x6ba
         "The RPC server is unavailable."
         ......................... SDC failed test DFSREvent
      Starting test: SysVolCheck
         ......................... SDC passed test SysVolCheck
      Starting test: KccEvent
         The event log Directory Service on server sdc.sea.nr could not be queried, error 0x6ba
         "The RPC server is unavailable."
         ......................... SDC failed test KccEvent
      Starting test: KnowsOfRoleHolders
         ......................... SDC passed test KnowsOfRoleHolders
      Starting test: MachineAccount
         ......................... SDC passed test MachineAccount
      Starting test: NCSecDesc
         ......................... SDC passed test NCSecDesc
      Starting test: NetLogons
         Unable to connect to the NETLOGON share! (\\SDC\netlogon)
         [SDC] An net use or LsaPolicy operation failed with error 67, The network name cannot be found..
         ......................... SDC failed test NetLogons
      Starting test: ObjectsReplicated
         ......................... SDC passed test ObjectsReplicated
      Starting test: Replications
         ......................... SDC passed test Replications
      Starting test: RidManager
         ......................... SDC passed test RidManager
      Starting test: Services
         Could not open Remote ipc to [sdc.sea.nr]: error 0x43 "The network name cannot be found."
         ......................... SDC failed test Services
      Starting test: SystemLog
         The event log System on server sdc.sea.nr could not be queried, error 0x6ba "The RPC server is unavailabl
         ......................... SDC failed test SystemLog
      Starting test: VerifyReferences
         ......................... SDC passed test VerifyReferences


   Running partition tests on : ForestDnsZones
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : DomainDnsZones
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : Schema
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Schema passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Schema passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : Configuration
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Configuration passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Configuration passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : sea
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... sea passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... sea passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running enterprise tests on : sea.nr
      Starting test: LocatorCheck
         Warning: DcGetDcName(GC_SERVER_REQUIRED) call failed, error 1717
         A Global Catalog Server could not be located - All GC's are down.
         Warning: DcGetDcName(PDC_REQUIRED) call failed, error 1717
         A Primary Domain Controller could not be located.
         The server holding the PDC role is down.
         Warning: DcGetDcName(TIME_SERVER) call failed, error 1717
         A Time Server could not be located.
         The server holding the PDC role is down.
         Warning: DcGetDcName(GOOD_TIME_SERVER_PREFERRED) call failed, error 1717
         A Good Time Server could not be located.
         Warning: DcGetDcName(KDC_REQUIRED) call failed, error 1717
         A KDC could not be located - All the KDCs are down.
         ......................... sea.nr failed test LocatorCheck
      Starting test: Intersite
         ......................... sea.nr passed test Intersite
```

It seems the server was trying to connect to sdc.sea.nr which is the name I inted to rename. But currently the computer name is still showing the old one and I couldn't add a A record in local DNS server. How should I fix that?

Comment: Reinstall. Lesson: never work with only one DC. Especially for a test domain they do not equire a lot of ressources, so there is no excuse not to have two (assuming virtualization, which one should generally use for things like that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution:

1. Modify the registry, change all the computer names:

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName
   Key Name: ComputerName

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ActiveComputerName
   Key Name: ComputerName

   HKey_Local_Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\TCPIP\ Parameters
   Key Name: NVHostName
2. Edit

   C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

   Add my ip address and the computer name.
3. Reboot.